# Streaming API subscription endpoint

Tags: rest-api, streaming-api

While I can dynamically create push topics through the API, I'm having trouble figuring out how to subscribe to them. Is there an endpoint that lets me pass in auth credentials and a callback URL, or do I have to use CometD to actually start listening to a push topic?

Answer (score 0):

Use EMP Connector (https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector) you just need to provide username , Password and security token , endpoint and other details are handled internally, after login you can check endpoint in BayeuxParam